# Jekyll + Jemoji : How to config emoji size?

Tags: jekyll, emoji

I am using Jekyll / jemoji on Github Pages.

When I wrote a markdown document as follows ..

```
* :tada: sample emoji markdown
```

.., it was rendered like this.

```html
<li>::marker
<img class="emoji" title=":tada" alt=":tada:" src= ... height="20" width="20">
" sample emoji markdown"
</li>
```

This image height & width always have same values ( height="20", width="20).

Sometimes I felt this emoji size is too small but I couldn't find any document about how to config "*jemoji*" ( and I don't know any Ruby language)

What I want to know are like these

1. How to config default emoji height and width
2. How to config inline custom values for emoji height and width within markdown document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from another plugin.

I changed the plugin of emoji processing from [jemoji](https://github.com/jekyll/jemoji) to [jekyll-spaceship](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship).

It seems that `jemoji` influenced `Jekyll-spaceship` plugin; they are using same example as follows.

```
I give this plugin two :+1:!
```

Anyway, I tested the following markdown expression with `jekyll-spaceship`.

```
* I give this plugin two :+1:!
```

This is rendered like this.

```html
<li>
::marker
"I give this plugin two"
<img class= "emoji" title=":+1:" alt=":+1:" raw="<emoji>" src=... style=" ..., max-width: 1em; ...", onload=".." onerror="...">
"!"
</li>
```

The image `max-width` attribute is not an absolute value !!
This shows me the width can be changed by its font size.
In this case the default setting of size attribute doesn't matter anymore.

I need to find how to set custom size of emoji when it is needed

So I tested the following markdown expression for the 'custom emoji size` and it looks like I found the solution.

```
### 8. Emoji Usage :+1:

* I give this plugin two :+1:!

<style>
.emoji-big-size img {font-size: 4rem;}
</style>

{: .emoji-big-size}
* I give this plugin two :+1:!
```

My browser show me the following result.

[image]